# How to update the clicked element only using useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a product structure which is taken by every new product dynamically.

so in the structure of the product I have an add to cart icon, and I want to replace the clicked icon only with a spinner svg.
but the problem is that all the icons is taking the change not the specific element only, so how can I update the state for the clicked item only, without using an array of icons or anything that making it static.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { FiShoppingCart } from "react-icons/fi";

const Carpet = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(<FiShoppingCart />);

return (
 <>
   {products.map((carpet) => (
    <div
      className="shrink-0 cursor-pointer w-[18rem] sm:max-w-sm"
      key={carpet.id}
    >
      <div className="relative">
        <img
          src={carpet.image.url}
          alt="carpet"
          className="object-cover h-[18em] w-80 rounded-xl"
        />
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            setLoading(
              <svg
                aria-hidden="true"
                class="w-6 h-6 animate-spin text-slate-300 fill-blue-500"
                viewBox="0 0 100 101"
                fill="none"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <path
                  d="M100 50.5908C100 78.2051 77.6142 100.591 50 100.591C22.3858 
                  100.591 0 78.2051 0 50.5908C0 22.9766 22.3858 0.59082 50 
                  0.59082C77.6142 0.59082 100 22.9766 100 50.5908ZM9.08144 
                  50.5908C9.08144 73.1895 27.4013 91.5094 50 91.5094C72.5987 91.5094 
                  90.9186 73.1895 90.9186 50.5908C90.9186 27.9921 72.5987 9.67226 50 
                  9.67226C27.4013 9.67226 9.08144 27.9921 9.08144 50.5908Z"
                  fill="currentColor"
                />
                <path
                  d="M93.9676 39.0409C96.393 38.4038 97.8624 35.9116 97.0079 
                  33.5539C95.2932 28.8227 92.871 24.3692 89.8167 20.348C85.8452 
                  15.1192 80.8826 10.7238 75.2124 7.41289C69.5422 4.10194 63.2754 
                  1.94025 56.7698 1.05124C51.7666 0.367541 46.6976 0.446843 41.7345 
                  1.27873C39.2613 1.69328 37.813 4.19778 38.4501 6.62326C39.0873 
                  9.04874 41.5694 10.4717 44.0505 10.1071C47.8511 9.54855 51.7191 
                  9.52689 55.5402 10.0491C60.8642 10.7766 65.9928 12.5457 70.6331 
                  15.2552C75.2735 17.9648 79.3347 21.5619 82.5849 25.841C84.9175 
                  28.9121 86.7997 32.2913 88.1811 35.8758C89.083 38.2158 91.5421 
                  39.6781 93.9676 39.0409Z"
                  fill="currentFill"
                />
              </svg>
            );
            setTimeout(function () {
              setLoading(<FiShoppingCart />);
            }, 1000);
            onAddToCart(carpet.id, 1);
          }}
          className={
            "absolute bg-white text-slate-500 hover:bg-slate-200 right-[1rem] bottom- 
            [1rem] p-4 text-xl rounded-full"
          }
        >
          {loading}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex justify-between p-2 py-4">
        <div>
          <h3 className="dark:text-white font-bold text-xl">
            {carpet.name}
          </h3>
          <p
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: carpet.description }}
            className="text-slate-400 text-sm"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-orange-500 to-yellow-500 flex items- 
           center justify-center h-10 px-5 rounded-lg font-bold ">
          ${carpet.price.formatted}
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
          ))}
        </>
        );
      };

     export default Carpet;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the loading product by its `id` and set the icon accordingly:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { FiShoppingCart } from 'react-icons/fi';

const Carpet = ({ products, onAddToCart }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(-1);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    setLoading(id);
    setTimeout(function () {
      setLoading(-1);
    }, 1000);
    onAddToCart(id, 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {products.map((carpet) => (
        <div
          className='shrink-0 cursor-pointer w-[18rem] sm:max-w-sm'
          key={carpet.id}
        >
          <div className='relative'>
            <img
              src={carpet.image.url}
              alt='carpet'
              className='object-cover h-[18em] w-80 rounded-xl'
            />
            <div
              onClick={() => handleClick(carpet.id)}
              className='absolute bg-white text-slate-500 hover:bg-slate-200 right-[1rem] bottom-[1rem] p-4 text-xl rounded-full'
            >
              {loading === carpet.id ? (
                <your-loading-svg />
              ) : (
                <FiShoppingCart />
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className='flex justify-between p-2 py-4'>
            <div>
              <h3 className='dark:text-white font-bold text-xl'>
                {carpet.name}
              </h3>
              <p
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: carpet.description }}
                className='text-slate-400 text-sm'
              />
            </div>
            <div
              className='bg-gradient-to-r from-orange-500 to-yellow-500 flex items- 
         center justify-center h-10 px-5 rounded-lg font-bold '
            >
              ${carpet.price.formatted}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default Carpet;
```